# Is it possible to define a completly different sub domain in the url for deployment slots in Azure?

Tags: azure, azureportal

I'm new to Azure portal and some subjects are still very fresh to me, which means my following question might be basic.

I would like to know if it's possible to have deployment slots associated to an app service that have a completly different sub domain in the URL.

As an example lets say i have this URL defined for the app service:

`potato.azurewebsites.net`

Now when i create a deployment slot and give it a name, for example `tomato`
what's happening is that it appends to the subdomain of the app service

`potato-tomato.azurewebsites.net`

Is there a way to name it only `tomato.azurewebsites.net` ?

[image]

Adding custom domains to the app service help to solve this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add the slot to the app service, the URL will always be `appservicename-slotname.azurewebsites.net`.

If you want it to meet your requirement, as you mentioned, you can add a [custom domain](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/manage-custom-dns-buy-domain) for the slot(**Note**: The custom domain should be added to the slot, not the app service).